# Permission problem deleting file in python

Tags: python

I generate a file in the `tmp` directory of my root server.

```
touch "sync.txt"
chmod 777 "sync.txt"
```

and I try to delete it with python like this

```
os.remove('/tmp/sync.txt')
```

but I always get this error

```
exceptions.OSError: [Errno 1] Operation not permitted: '/tmp/sync.txt'
```

I thought this would be solved by settings the file permission to 777 but I still have this problem.

When I make

```
chmod 777 /tmp
```

instead I get another error:

```
exceptions.OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/tmp/sync.txt'
```

However the file is deleted.

Any idea whats wrong? How can I fix that exception?

Comment: have you tried `sudo myscript.py` ?

Comment: Files in /tmp are automatically chown'ed to user, who creates them. If user running python application is not same one, who created the file, then you won't be able to delete it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If `/tmp` is marked [**sticky**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sticky_bit) (`chmod a+t`) then only the superuser or the owner of the directory or file within it will be able to delete it, regardless of what permissions the file has.

Answer (score 0):

By default, everyone can write in `/tmp`. You need to `chown [python_running_user]:[its_group] /tmp/sync.txt`. `chmod 777 /tmp/sync.txt` is not mandatory. `644` will be enough.